# UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage received memory warning in iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, didreceivememorywarning

I have a UICollectionView and a bar button at top right(CameraViewController1 : UICollectionViewController).The flow is when I take a picture it moves to a new view controller where the image can be cropped.User has two option Use and Cancel after choosing any of this option it gets back the image to the collection view and it gets arranged like cells.I want to take many photos.But I can take up to 3 pictures then the app crashes

This happens only in iPhone 4 not in iPhone 5.

Why the app gets crash only on iPhone 4 ? The same code perfectly working in iPhone 5.

I want a good image quality when I look back in a image view Using the line `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` gives me the good quality but it gets crash in iPhone 4 any solution please !

What are the possible things I should do in this class to get rid of this memory warning (cause in iPhone 4) ?

I tried resizing image but it gives me a poor quality image.Is it possible to get a good quality image even after resizing ?

Please Help ! How to get rid of this memory warning ?

Here the complete code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:FALSE withAnimation:NO];

    [barbutton setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                        UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0],
                                        UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor blueColor]
                                        } forState:UIControlStateNormal];



  hide_backbtn=1;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=7.0)
    {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    }



    //self.collection_view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bottom.png"]];

    self.collectionView.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bottom.png"]]autorelease];//ar

    [super viewDidLoad];
   crop_one.hidden=TRUE;
    view_refresh=3;


     selectedRecipes = [NSMutableArray array];
 //noww   imgSmall=[[[UIImage alloc]init]autorelease];//ar



    picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker1.delegate = self;

    if (! (picker1==nil)) {

        NSLog(@"YUCCKKK");


    }
    if ((picker1==nil)&&(original_image < 0)) {
        NSLog(@"YEEEEEEYYYYYYYYY");
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}




- (IBAction)TakeaPhoto:(id)sender {



        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:FALSE withAnimation:NO];


    gallery=0;


    picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;


       self.resizeableCropArea =YES;
   self.cropSize=CGSizeMake(300,350);//296, 350

   // picker1.allowsEditing = YES;

    [self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self.picker1 release];

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


    UIImage *image =[info   objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] ;


    CGSize sizeCropped = CGSizeMake(600,800);//you can give any size 320, 370
   // UIImage *theimage = nil;
 image = [self resizeImage:image newSize:sizeCropped];



     CropViewController *cropController = [[CropViewController alloc] init];

    cropController.sourceImage=image;



     cropController.sourceImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; //now


      Original_img = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(cropController.sourceImage,0.0);   ///////now

    [original_image addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:Original_img]]; // nowwww       



    NSLog(@"source image=%@",cropController.sourceImage);


    cropController.resizeableCropArea = self.resizeableCropArea;

    cropController.cropSize = self.cropSize;


    cropController.delegate = self;


    Cancel_Image= cropController.sourceImage;


    [self.navigationController
     pushViewController:cropController animated:YES];

    [cropController release];


}

- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}

//- (UIImage*)imageTemp:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
//{
//  
//  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
//  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];//newSize.width,newSize.height)
//    
//  UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//  
//  return newImage;
//    
//    
//    
//    
//}



- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {


     [picker1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{



    return [image_name count];



    //  [self.collection_view cellForItemAtIndexPath:];
}




- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    int row = indexPath.row;

   recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];




 //UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    //UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

   //[recipeImageView setImage:image];
 //recipeImageView.image = image_cap;


    recipeImageView.image = (UIImage*) [image_name objectAtIndex:row];



    // cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];

   //cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bottom.png"]];

 cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];


    return cell;
}



-(void)sample
{
//    NSLog(@"%@",destViewController.recipeImageName);

}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        NSString *deSelectedRecipe = [image_name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [selectedRecipes removeObject:deSelectedRecipe];

}
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{

        return YES;

}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    mt_img=1;

     NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];


    hide_backbtn=1;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    recipeImageName = [image_name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 if(appDelegate.intAddOrView==2)
 {
     hide_backbtn=20;
 }

     selected_image=indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"%@",recipeImageName);

     [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath1 animated:NO];

   [arrInsertReceipt replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject: [image_name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //now

}
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
  // UIView *tappedView = [gesture.view hitTest:[gesture locationInView:gesture.view] withEvent:nil];
    NSLog(@"Touch event ");
    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];


    if (indexPath)
    {
        NSLog(@"Image was double tapped");
    }

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:FALSE withAnimation:NO];


    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];



    [barbutton setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                        UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0],
                                        UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor blueColor]
                                        } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=7.0)
    {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    }

   // [self viewDidLoad];
    [collection_view reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

       // [localarray removeAllObjects];
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    NSLog(@"CAMERA VIEW CONTROLLER 1 MEMORY WARNING");

   // NSLog(@"HERERERERER");


    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{


    [original_image removeAllObjects];
    recipeImageView.image=nil;

}



@end
```

Updated:
CAMERA VIEW CONTROLLER 1 MEMORY WARNING and CROP VIEW CONTROLLER MEMORY WARNING 
are my NSLog statements I kept under `didReceiveMemoryWarning`

[image: Console Output]

Comment: what is OS version in both devices? Could you show crash logs?

Comment: @Mani iPhone 4 = 7.0.2 iPhone 5 = 7.0.4, also updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this method :

```
-(UIImage *)getResizedImageForImage:(UIImage *)originalImage forSize:(CGSize)size
{
     @autoreleasepool
     {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

       [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

       UIImage * finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

       return finalImage;
     }
}
```

Here we have used @autoreleasepool, So, it will be reduced the memory warning.

Thanks!